# JavaScript/html show alert which includes label input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using HTML5 and JavaScript

I want to be able to input any word into a label and when you click on the button it gives an alert which includes the given text.

I cannot get it to work with the text I put into the label the alert shows no text.
I've only found how to do it with predefined labels.

Here's my current html code

```js
function getinput() {
  var input = document.getElementById("form-scream").innerText;
  alert(input);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Word
    <label id="form-scream"></label>

    <input type="text" name="screaming" id="form-scream">

    <button onclick="getinput()"> Click to scream</button>
  </p>
  <script src="assets/js/scream.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Your label needs `for="form-scream"` instead, your current code assigns the id to the label itself instead of the <input>. (using an `id` multiple times is invalid and `getElementById()` will return the first match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` element does not have `innerText` property, use `value` instead. Also, you have use `for` attribute in a label to associate an element (the element's `id` as the value of `for`):

```js
function getinput()
{
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("form-scream").value;
  alert(inputVal);
};
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Word
    <label for="form-scream"></label>

    <input type="text" name="screaming" id="form-scream">

    <button onclick="getinput()"> Click to scream</button>
    </p>
    <script src="assets/js/scream.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: okay thank you! I'll search what the difference is between id and for.